# Filtering array in JavaScript and outputting to DOM - repetition

Tags: javascript

Sample code below - it works, but feels clunky.

`clients` is provided from a DB as a `json_encoded` array of objects (in the real app this is several hundred items.)

**Objective:** filter the list based on user input, which can be a partial case-insensitive string of `code` or `name`.

The user knows in advance what the `id` or `name` is - this is to quickly reduce the list to possible matches, to save them from scrolling through hundreds.

```js
 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    const clients = [{ id: 1, name: "Bob Marley", code: "BM1" }, { id: 2, name: "Elton John", code:"EJ1" }, { id: 3, name: "Beach Boys", code: "BB1" }, { id: 4, name: "Boyzone", code: "BO1" }];
    const clientsList = document.getElementById("clientsList");
    const search = document.getElementById("search");

    // handle empty client array?

    if (clients.length === 0) {
        clientsList.innerHTML = '<li>No clients were found.</li>';
    } else {

        // populate the list initially
        const listArray = clients.map((element) =>
            '<li><a href="/clients/view/' + element.id + '">' + element.name + '</a></li>'
        ).join("");

        clientsList.innerHTML = listArray;

        search.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
            clientsList.innerHTML = clients.filter((value) =>
                value.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) ||
                value.code.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
            ).map((element) =>
                '<li><a href="/clients/view/' + element.id + '">' + element.name + '</a></li>').join("");
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
<ul id="clientsList"></ul>

<!-- Sample input / output
bo => bob marley, beach boys, boyzone
on => elton john, boyzone
bm1 => bob marley -->
```

I don't like that there is repetition in generating the `li element` and `url` - I thought about creating a function and then using that in the `map`?

```
const generateListElement = (client_id, name) => `<li><a href="/clients/view/${client_id}">${name}</a></li>`;


...map((element) => generateListElement(element.id, element.name)
```

but that doesn't look much better.

good, bad, ugly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove the outer `if else`**

```
if (clients.length === 0) {
  clientsList.innerHTML = '<li>No clients were found.</li>';
  return;
}
```

---

**Decouple `const clients`**

Make a function. For now `clients` is hard coded, later rewritten to work with the JSON object. *The function call will not change*

```
 const clients = fetchWhateverThatDataIs();

 function fetchWhateverThatDataIs() {
    return [{ id: 1, name: "Bob Marley", code: "BM1" }, { id: 2, name: "Elton John", code:"EJ1" }, { id: 3, name: "Beach Boys", code: "BB1" }, { id: 4, name: "Boyzone", code: "BO1" }];
 }
```

---

**Objects organize functionality then simplify client code**

A `Clients` object will encapsulate `filter` and `HtmlList`.

```
function Clients (theClients) {
  this.clients = theClients ? theClients : [];
  
  this.isEmpty = function() { return this.clients.length === 0; }

  this.HtmlList = function () {
     return this.clients.map((element) =>
        '<li><a href="/clients/view/' + element.id + '">' + element.name + '</a></li>'
    ).join("");
  } //HtmlList

  // intended as an event handler
  this.filter = function (event) {
    this.clients.filter((value) =>           
      value.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) ||
      value.code.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
    ).map((element) =>
       '<li><a href="/clients/view/' + element.id + '">' + element.name + '</a></li>').join("");
  } //filter

} //Clients
```

---

The `<li>` building is repeated. For now I'm inclined to follow my rule "repeated once, think about refactoring; repeated twice (or more), refactor." In any case make sure this initial refactoring works first.

---

> it works, but feels clunky

Not any more.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  const clients = new Clients(fetchWhateverThatDataIs());
  const clientsList = document.getElementById("clientsList");
  const search = document.getElementById("search");

  if (clients.isEmpty()) {
    clientsList.innerHTML = '<li>No clients were found.</li>';
    return;
  }

  clientsList.innerHTML = clients.HtmlList();

  search.addEventListener("keyup", clients.filter);

});
```

Comment: wow - very helpful, fhank you!